# Camera gets frozen when I come back to the app (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a custom camera function for my app, but when I go out from the app and come back, the camera is frozen. How can I fix this?

I want the camera to resume when the user opens the app again, instead of having to close the app and re-open it again.

Code:

```
AVCaptureSession *session;
AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];

    if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput]) {
        [session addInput:deviceInput];
    }

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    CGRect frame = frameForCapture.frame;

    [previewLayer setFrame:frame];
    [rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
    [session startRunning];

    crossButton.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender 
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {

        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {

            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                crossButton.hidden = NO;
                cameraButton.hidden = YES;
                break;

            }

        }

    }

    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {

            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            imageView.image = image;

        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you are using `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods to configure your camera in your application.

use `viewDidLoad` method to configure camera this will called once whenever the view controller needs to load its view hierarchy.

**Reason**: Methods `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` called every time whenever app navigate back to the same `viewController`.