# Run code as soon as a specific view controller is loaded

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have some view controllers like this: [image: Storyboard]

I want to show the Login page as soon as the protected page is triggered via a button click event.

I am unable to figure out how I can know whether the particular view (protected page) was loaded or not?

How should I write the code for that?

Comment: In your protectedViewController.m file have override methods, like viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, etc. From that you can get whether the page was loaded or not. Refer this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a read now... Can you tell me one more thing?
Is code for every ViewController written in the ViewController.swift originally provided (when the Xcode project is created)?

Comment: yes, viewDidLoad() originally provide in the ViewController when project created or any new VC created

Answer (score 1):

Assign the seperate class **using attribute inspector inside storyboard** to each `viewController` or assign same accordingly in order to run code for specific `viewController` *see image below* and work with those `viewController` life cycle methods `viewDidLoad` `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` and from here see the short [description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39178358/4003548) to learn more about these methods ..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ViewController` subclass for `ProtectedViewController`.
Set that class in your storyboard by selecting the ViewController and using the Identity Inspector on the right panel.
Override `viewDidLoad` in ProtectedViewController.m to do what you would like to do when `ProtectedViewController` is loaded.